# Print out 6 distinct numbers in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    // Create new 6 Pot
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val pot = listOf<Pot>(Pot(50), Pot(50), Pot(50), Pot(50), Pot(50), Pot(50))
    val linearLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.text)
    linearLayout.removeAllViews()
    // random 6 number from 1 - 50 without duplicate
    // Create textview to print out roll result

    pot.forEach {
        val d = it
        val rollResult = d.roll()
        list.add(rollResult)
        val textView = TextView(this)
        textView.append(this.toString())
        val param = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        param.marginStart = 10
        textView.layoutParams = param
        textView.text = rollResult.toString()
        linearLayout.addView(textView)
    }
```

I have a code like this, after add `rollResult` to a `list` like a temp paper, what should i do to compare next result to previous result which is in the `list`, if it already present then do another roll, from start to end. Thanks

Comment: not sufficient details provided to help you out, try to break your problem into smaller parts as well as show us some more code

Comment: I'm simulating a luckydraw machine with 6 different numbers range from 1-50 and not duplicate. I created a list to contains the results of the roll, and compare the next result with the previous result. If the result is the same, roll it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct()`,

Ref : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html

Example

```
var list = listOf(1,2,4,5,1,6,8,2,4,3,3,5)
list = list.distinct();
println(list)
```

First loop for generating roll results

```
pot.forEach {
        val d = it
        val rollResult = d.roll()
        list.add(rollResult)
}
```

Second Loop for adding dynamic views

```
list = list.distinct();
list.forEach {
 // Add Views etc
}
```

Modify as per your needs.

Comment: Really appeciate your answer but i want to use `val list = mutableListOf<Int>()` because the numbers of pot is unpredicted, so as i can see `distinct()` is not available for this situation, right ?

Comment: you can assign to different var or change list variable type to List like var list = listOf<Int>()

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the element is present in the whole list or not try below code :

```
if(list.contains(element)){ // do rollout again}
```

Comment: I tried this but when i add action do rollout again, somehow it doesnt work. Still have duplicate result.